# docker ubuntu container exec bash issue

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I pull & run an image like

```
docker run -d --name=lemp \
  -v /Users/bappa/Desktop/server/www:/var/www/ \
  -p 8080:80 \
  stenote/docker-lemp:16.04
```

& then go to bash like

```
docker exec -it lemp bash
```

which is absolutely fine. But When I do with `ubuntu:16.04` image same thing. I found response like below
[image]
Where is the problem? why the container exit? Thanks.

Comment: You should [check the logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) (with `docker logs lemp` in your case).

Comment: @tripleee that's not an error message its a process which is difficult to explain.

Comment: It's text and you posted it as an image. Transcribing it is a drudge and error-prone whereas you could have just copy/pasted it easily. See http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that caused the different behavior is because of their Dockerfile CMD or ENTRYPOINT.

Once the main process (CMD or ENTRYPOINT) finishes, a docker container stops.

If you look at [docker-lemp Dockerfile](https://github.com/stenote/docker-lemp/blob/master/Dockerfile):

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comparing to [Ubuntu Dockerfile](https://github.com/dockerfile/ubuntu/blob/master/Dockerfile):

```
CMD ["bash"]
```

docker-lemp runs entrypoint.sh which runs further processes that remain in the foreground while Ubuntu runs bash that quits itself after completion.

If you want to keep Ubuntu in the background, a simple trick would be:

```
docker container run -d ubuntu:16.04 tail -f /dev/null
```

This replaces the default CMD **bash** with **tail -f /dev/null** so the container does not exits.

Comment: completely understand the issue.